# wrong offsetHeight because of 'Nunito' font.. How to get real element height with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I was struggling to find out why '.offsetHeight' was not giving me the correct value then I found out the font was to blame. I need to know if there is a solution while still using the same font.. please check the below information:

Height according to the browser inspector ( correct value, considers the correct content height, paddings and border ):
[image: correct offsetHeight value by browser]

When I console.log the '.offsetHeight' of these 3 items, these are the values I get:

[image: console log of offsetHeight not considering font]

those are not the correct offsetHeight values!!

I only got the correct/matching values (browser inspector height === offsetHeight) when I removed 'Nunito' font, for testing purposes...

Font I'm using:

```
<link
            href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap"
            rel="preload"
            as="style"
            onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet';"
        />
```

( or loading it normally, doesn't matter ):

```
<link
            href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
```

If I remove that font, or simply change the font-family to 'Arial' for example that I get the correct offsetHeight:

[image: offsetHeight without font]

This is interfering with some vertical aligning that I am doing with JS!

I saw many people in the internet struggle also with the 'offsetHeight' maybe the font is also their issue..

Is there a solution for this?